# how to make a gradle build using only the local dependencies?

Tags: gradle

I am trying to make a `gradle build.`

The repositories are now unaccessible (due my internet connection).

But I had made a build with those libraries already and are compiled at my computer locally.

I want to make a gradle build without going to the internet and look for them, instead, want to fetch them locally.

I have tried adding this:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        ...
```

But is not really working, any idea how to do it? or through the command line?

Comment: did you try `--offline` option?  see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_execution_options

Comment: thanks @M.Ricciuti, that worked out the problem

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 places where you can declare your repositories, each of them affects different things in the build.

The one you mentioned, within the `buildscript` only states that *for this buildscript (build.gradle), resolve the dependencies (practically classes) from the local maven repository*.

If you want to resolve the dependencies which you declared under the `dependencies` block, you have to go straight with

```
repositories {
    mavenLocal()
}
```

Comment: Please note, that the local Maven repository is **not** the same as the Gradle cache. Any packages in `mavenLocal()` must be installed manually.